# MxNet: Good ways to infer on large image datasets

Tags: python, mxnet, gluon

I have millions of images to infer on. I know how to write my own code  to create batches and forward the batches to a trained network using [MxNet Module API](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/index.html) in order to get the predictions. However, creating the batches leads to a lot of data manipulation that is not especially optimized.

Before doing any optimisation myself, I would like to know if there are some recommended approaches for batch predictions/inferences. More specifically, since this is a common use case, I was wondering if there is  an interface/api that can do the usual image pre-processing, batch creation, and inference given a trained model (i.e. symbole file & epoch checkpoint)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a standard pretrained model, I would highly recommend to take a look into [gluoncv project](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/) - a toolkit for Computer Vision based on Apache MXNet.

They have really nice implementations of state of the art models, sometimes even beating the original results that are published in scientific papers. What is cool is that they also provide the data preprocessing code - as far as I understand, this is what you are looking for. (see `gluoncv.data.transforms.presets` package).

I don't know which inference you want to do, like image classification, segmentation, etc, but take a look to the [list of tutorials](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/tutorials/index.html) and most probably you will find one you need.

Other than that, optimization for the fast wall clock time requires you to make sure that your GPU is 100% utilized. You may find useful to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cqo7FPftNyo) to learn more about tips and tricks on optimizing performance. It discusses training, but the same techniques applies to inference.